# Why might string concatenation prefix each concatenation with garbage?

Tags: c, string, memory, memory-management

I'm pretty new to C, so I apologize if this is pretty standard knowledge..

I have a function like so, where I am appending a bunch of C-style strings together and outputting it:

```
char *example(int n, int days, int years){
    char *ret;
    if (n < 5) {
        ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        sprintf(ret, "There are %d days in %d years", days, years);
        ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));
        return ret;
    }
    else {
        char *s1;
        char *s2;
        char *s3;
        s1 = example(n/2, days, years);
        s2 = example(n + 5, days, years);
        s3 = example(n--, days, years);

        int length = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3);
        ret = (char*)malloc(length);
        strcat(ret, s1);
        strcat(ret, s2);
        strcat(ret, s3);

        return ret;
       }
}
```

This is prefixing each of the new concatenations with a few garbage characters.  I'm assuming my issue is in my memory management, but I'm not sure.. Is this simple?  What have I done wrong?  Also, how can this be done cleaner?

Comment: Yikes!!! The recursion!!! Where are you going to release all the memory?

Comment: Good question!  How do you release memory you're returning like that?  Things I should probably think of..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *example(int n, int days, int years){
   char *ret;
   if (n < 5) {
       ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
       sprintf(ret, "There are %d days in %d years", days, years);
//     ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));  (DELETE THIS LINE)
       return ret;
   }
   else {
       char *s1;
       char *s2;
       char *s3;
       s1 = example(n/2, days, years);
       s2 = example(n + 5, days, years);  // WILL THIS CAUSE INFINITE RECURSION?
       s3 = example(n--, days, years);

       int length = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + 1; // ALLOW ROOM FOR TERMINATING '\0'
       ret = (char*)malloc(length);
       strcpy(ret, s1);  // CHANGE TO strcpy()
       strcat(ret, s2);
       strcat(ret, s3);

       return ret;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the infinite recursion, it was an example method based on my own :)  you're right, though.  good catch!

Answer (score 1):

You allocate a chunk of memory, write into it with sprintf, then throw away the first buffer and replace it with a new buffer of undefined contents.

```
    ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    sprintf(ret, "There are %d days in %d years", days, years);
    ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));
    return ret;
```

Deleting the third line will likely help.

Answer (score 1):

strlen() returns the number of characters NOT including the terminating zero ('\0').
When allocating memory you should add 1 to strlen() to hold that zero char.

You should put that '\0' manually at the beginning of your string or use strcpy() instead of the first strcat().

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
sprintf(ret, "There are %d days in %d years", days, years);
ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));
```

is allocating some memory, writing a string into that memory, and then allocating and returning new, uninitialised memory.

This:

```
ret = (char*)malloc(length);
strcat(ret, s1);
```

is appending `s1` to `ret`, which is uninitialised. You need to do

```
ret[0] = '\0'
```

after allocating the memory to initialise it as a zero-length string.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you write that call to reallocate the string?

```
ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));
```

How do you suppose that the characters you put into that string in the line above it would make it over to the newly-allocated memory?

Take that second call to `malloc` out and see if that helps. Also, when you allocate the string in the "else" clause, you need to make room for the terminating null character, so add 1 to your "length".  Right after the `malloc` call, set `*ret` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use c for a very long time but...
In case the `n < 5` you have the following code:

```
ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
sprintf(ret, "There are %d days in %d years", days, years);
ret = (char*)malloc(strlen(ret));
```

why do you need the last line?